# Translating Django admin interface

Tags: django, translation

I'm trying to customize Django generated admin interface so it will display in my native language Hebrew (including right-to-left orientation) but I cant seem to find an how-to or any reference whatsoever.
The [Django translation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/) hasn't given me a clear answer, even though apparently someone already created an [Hebrew translation](https://github.com/django/django/commit/8a861942cd).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have info you look for: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/i18n/localization/

Edit:

I didn't found that page on 1.4 docs but here it is for 1.3 which should be still correct.
AFAIK nothing changed in that matter in 1.4.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/localization/

Edit2:

Here is info for django 1.4 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/

Info about generating po files is here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#message-files

Comment: This seems to be from an older Django version (1.1 vs 1.4 im using). still applies?

Comment: Ahh sorry i didn't not noticed that. Here is for version 1.3 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/localization/ Which should still apply and be fresher.

Comment: All links are dead :(